# How do you add a sparkline chart inside of a kendo angular grid?

Tags: angular, typescript, charts, kendo-ui, sparklines

I am trying to make the first column in my grid show a bullet chart.

```
<kendo-grid-column>
    <ng-template kendoChartSeriesTooltipTemplate let-value="value">
      <div>
        <kendo-sparkline [data]="bulletData" type="bullet" [valueAxis]="bulletValueAxis">
        </kendo-sparkline>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>

 public bulletData: any[] = [21, 23];
  public bulletValueAxis: any = {
    min: 0,
    max: 30,
    plotBands: [{
      from: 0, to: 15, color: "#787878", opacity: 0.15
    }, {
      from: 15, to: 22, color: "#787878", opacity: 0.3
    }, {
      from: 22, to: 30, color: "#787878", opacity: 0.15
    }]
  };
```

The column is not showing anything. It is just empty.

Answer (score 0):

The directive to use in the `ng-template` is a `kendoGridCellTemplate` to show the chart in the first column (not `kendoChartSeriesTooltipTemplate`).

Further, make sure you `import 'hammerjs';`

See the complete Stackblitz example here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bxspfv